# How to recover the old data from table

Tags: sql

I have made an update statement in a table in SQL 2008 which updated the table with some wrong data.

I didn't have a backup for the DB.

It's some important dates which got updated.

Is there anyway where i can recover the old data from the table.

Thanks

SNA

Comment: Let this be a lesson for you: always test your update statements and always take a backup before you make any broad changes.

Comment: @Welbog: perhaps it wasn't *meant* to be a broad change ;)

Comment: @David Hedlund: See step one of the lesson: always test your update statements.

Comment: also, @swapna: sorry for the tone here. we're not being pretentious; if we could save your day we would - it's just that there's simply no solution to this, unless you're lucky and some of the old data is still on disc, in which case Andrew's suggestion would work.

Comment: @Welbog: so you meant " test your update statements *although not in your live environment* "? ohhhhhhh

Comment: @David : There is the manual decoding solution; given enough time, the log file, the mdf for the schema it is posible to decode a log file transaction by hand and get the old values, but it's incredibly slow, hard and barely documented. It would take me weeks to do it - so let's not go there :)

Answer (score 6):

Basically no unless you want to use a commercial log reader and try go through it with a fine tooth comb. No backup of the database can be an 'update resume, leave town' scenario - harsh but it just should not happen.

Comment: don't forget the where clause or you might update *everybody's* resume :O

Answer (score 6):

Andrew basically has called it. I just want to add a few ideas you can consider if you are desperate:

1. Are there any reports or printouts lying around? Perhaps you can reconstruct the data from there.
2. Was this data entered via a web application? If so, there is a remote chance you can find the original data in the web server logs, depending upon how the app was constructed, etc.
3. Does this app interface (pass data to) any other applications? They may have a buffered copy of data...
4. Can the data be derived from any other existing data? Is there an audit log table, or another date in your schema based on this one, from which you can reconstruct the original date?

**Edit:**

Some commenters are mentioning that is is a good idea to test your update/delete statements before running them. For this to become habit, it helps if you have an easy method. I usually create my `DELETE` statements like this:

```
--delete --select * 
from [User]
where UserID=27
```

To run the select in order to test your query, highlight everything from `select` onwards. To then run the delete if you are satisfied with the filter criteria, highlight everything from `delete` onwards. The two dashes in front of `delete` are so that if the query accidentally gets run, it will just crash due to invalid syntax.

You can use a similar construct for `UPDATE` statements, although it is not quite as clean.

Comment: +1 for using the -- comment tag in sql.  This is embedded in my dna.

Answer (score 3):

SQL server keeps log for every transation.So you can recover your modified data from the log as well without backup.

```
Select [PAGE ID],[Slot ID],[AllocUnitId],[Transaction ID]
,[RowLog Contents 0], [RowLog Contents 1],[RowLog Contents 3],[RowLog Contents 4]
,[Log Record]
FROM    sys.fn_dblog(NULL, NULL)  
WHERE
AllocUnitId IN 
(Select [Allocation_unit_id] from sys.allocation_units allocunits
INNER JOIN sys.partitions partitions ON (allocunits.type IN (1, 3)  
AND partitions.hobt_id = allocunits.container_id) OR (allocunits.type = 2 
AND partitions.partition_id = allocunits.container_id)  
Where object_id=object_ID('' + 'dbo.student' + ''))
AND Operation in ('LOP_MODIFY_ROW','LOP_MODIFY_COLUMNS') 
And [Context] IN   ('LCX_HEAP','LCX_CLUSTERED')
```

Here is the artcile, that explains step by step, how to do it.
http://raresql.com/2012/02/01/how-to-recover-modified-records-from-sql-server-part-1/

Imran

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all the responses.

The problem was actually accidentally ---i missed to select the where condition in the update statement.---Rest !.

It was a quick 5 minutes task --Like just changing the date to test for one customer data--so we didn't think of taking a backup.

Yes of course you are true ..This is a lesson.

Now onwards i will be careful to write "my update statements in a transaction." or "test my update statements"

Thanks once again--for spending  your time to give some insight rather ignoring the question since the only answer is "NO".

Thanks

SNA

Comment: +1. For accepting the mistake and learning the lesson. Also, the DB here is of some constraint. If it is Oracle, you can use FLASHBACK option which will work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Always take a backup before major UPDATE statements, even if it's not used, there's the peace of mind

Especially with Red Gate's Object Level Restore, one can restore individual table/row now given a backup file

Good luck, I'd suggest finding an old copy elsewhere (DEV/QA) etc...

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it possible to do a rollback on an UPDATE statement?

Comment: Only if you were within a transaction and had not committed it.

Comment: Ie, so he probably didn't?  I guess this is a chalk-it-up-to-experience item.  Most of the DB guys I used to talk to always wrapped up all admin/maintenance operations in a txn.

Comment: Perhaps another valid point from "Andrew", always begin update st't with a transaction and verify it, commit it.

Answer (score 0):

Late one but hopefully useful…

If database is in full recovery mode then all transactions are logged in transaction log and can be retrieved. Problem is that this is not natively supported because this is not the main purpose of the transaction log.

Options are:

- Commercial tools such as [Apex Log](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_log.aspx) (more expensive, more options)  or [Quest Toad](http://www.quest.com/) (less expensive, less options for this purpose main focus is on SQL Server management)
- Trying to do this yourself, like user1059637 pointed out. Problem with this approach is that it can’t read transaction log backups and is more tedious.

  It comes down to how much your data is worth to you in terms of time and $.