# How to rollback an implicit SSMS transaction (statement with go at the end)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, transactions, ssms

Question: 
Normally, you can undo a sql command with rollback.

```
BEGIN TRY
  BEGIN TRANSACTION
  /* run all your SQL statements */
  COMMIT TRANSACTION
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
  ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
END CATCH
```

My question now:
If 'one' did this

```
UPDATE TABLE_X SET FIELD_X = 'bla'
GO
```

in **SSMS** (notice the go at the end) **and forgot to specify the WHERE clause**,
is it possible (and how) to rollback the implicit transaction that SSMS executed this command in (statements with go at the end are implicitly executed in a transaction) ?

Note:
I didn't do that, but a colleague of mine did a few days ago (without go).
I undid the damage he did (fortunately I made a backup 0.5 hours before he did that), but for the future, it would be good to know this, because this happened to me once, too.

Comment: Oh, a colleague, was it? :)

Comment: @podiluska: xD  It really was ! I know how dangerous updates are, because about a year ago, the same thing happened to me with the table containing the translations (ever since I know, the underlying problem is this thought process: it's only ONE update, what could POSSIBLY go wrong...)  ;)

Comment: You could always customise the default SSMS new query template to include `begin tran; rollback tran`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see the link below, I think it will help you

[How to recover the old data from table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2042208/how-to-recover-the-old-data-from-table/#answer-9107323)

thanks
Arun

Answer (score 4):

No, you can't, not easily. Restoring from backup is the best option.

Comment: Yes, you can. But not easily is true ;)

Answer (score 1):

`GO` does not specify the end of an implicit transaction, but the end of a batch. That's why you won't be able (unfortunately) to `ROLLBACK` your `UPDATE` after a `GO`.

From the [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188037(v=sql.100)) on `GO`:

> GO is not a Transact-SQL statement; it is a command recognized by the
>   sqlcmd and osql utilities and SQL Server Management Studio Code
>   editor.
>
> SQL Server utilities interpret GO as a signal that they should send
>   the current batch of Transact-SQL statements to an instance of SQL
>   Server. The current batch of statements is composed of all statements
>   entered since the last GO, or since the start of the ad hoc session or
>   script if this is the first GO.

The `UPDATE` command will only be seen as the start of an implicit transaction if you have specified `SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS ON;` (see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188317(v=sql.100))). In that case, a number of commands (`CREATE`, `DELETE`, `UPDATE` etcetera) will automatically start a new implicit transaction, and that transaction will not end until you issue a `ROLLBACK` or a `COMMIT`.

(See for more info on the difference between transactions and batches in SQL Server for example this question on ServerFault: [SQL Server: Statements vs. Batches vs. Transactions vs. Connections](https://serverfault.com/questions/127578/sql-server-statements-vs-batches-vs-transactions-vs-connections).)

Comment: True, the OP obviously means auto commit transactions. Implicit transactions would not have been committed automatically.